# Adding full-width content or re-structuring layout in Genesis Wordpress Child-Theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to add two pictures, both floated in opposing directions above the content of my word press theme,

I am going for this: *old link*

Here is a link to the site I am working on: *test link*

How could I create a wrap above the content, but below the header, and to take up 100% of the container?

I have tried creating a new wrap in the structure, but that does not work, it creates a container within site-inner. I've tried putting a text widget in the header area, but when I add a margin-top to it, the logo moves with it.

Edit:

I have since found out what I was doing wrong. I am using a genesis theme, and looked up the proper hooks. Ultimately I ended with this code,

```
add_action('genesis_after_header', 'add_featured_image');

function add_featured_image(){
echo get_the_post_thumbnail(  );
}
```

I used [this](http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/) as a visual reference, genesis_after_header is the location,right after the header in the layout. The code I referenced to earlier allows the user to set a featured image on the page or post panel, and it'll be displayed. If you want to fit it within a column, you will want to add it before content entry.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with "solved", just answer it.

Comment: @joeytje50 The solution was the code I included, was my explanation not very clear?

Comment: Normally, you write your answer as an answer (hence the name) and you can mark is accepted after 2 days. Editing your question to add the answer isn't the correct way.